# Add Storage Step in Launching Amazon EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am planning on launching a t1.medium instance into my VPC. On the *Add Storage* step, I am presented with the following:

[image]

With an m1.medium instance, I am supposed to get 1 x 410 gb of instance store based storage.

- What does the above show?
- Will the *Instance Store 0* type (with all of the N/A's) automatically default to the 410 gb?
- Is the Root type, with 8gb, also instance storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the AMI you are using, the Root volume is EBS. You can have all instance storage if you use an instance store only AMI.

Keep in min, even though instance storage is included in the instance rate. It should not be considered persistent. If you stop your instance (or the host hardware fails), and start it again later, you will lose all the data stored on the instance store volume.

Its not a good place to store a database unless you have a solid replication plan. But it can work well if you need a lot of temp space for processing data.

Comment: Thanks. Is it common practice to install software on the Root EBS partition, that will persist after instance stop/start? And I assume that the default 8gb is billed like typical EBS storage? Also, will *Instance Store 0* default to the 410 gb?

Comment: @littleK Yes to all your questions.

Comment: Note that it is possible to use Instance Store with an EBS-backed AMI -- the root volume (i.e., where your OS is installed and running from) would be an EBS, and your instance store volume(s) would be additional block devices (/dev/sd* in linux, or F:, G: etc in Windows).